# JQuery images scroll top when click

Tags: jquery, image, scroll

I need when I click in one image this scrolling to the top of the page.

```html
<p>one</p>
<img src="http://lavozdelmuro.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/cecil-el-leon-4.jpg" height="250" />
<p>two</p>
<img src="http://lavozdelmuro.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/cecil-el-leon-4.jpg" height="250" />
<p>three</p>
<img src="http://lavozdelmuro.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/cecil-el-leon-4.jpg" height="250" />
<p>four</p>
<img src="http://lavozdelmuro.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/cecil-el-leon-4.jpg" height="250" />
<p>five</p>
<img src="http://lavozdelmuro.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/cecil-el-leon-4.jpg" height="250" />
<p>six</p>
<img src="http://lavozdelmuro.net/wp-content/uploads/2015/07/cecil-el-leon-4.jpg" height="250" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code in your head tag, it will help u :-)

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('img').click(function(){
   $('html, body').animate({scrollTop : 0},800);
   return false;
});
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank's. This is to scrolling to the top of the page, but I need  go to the top of image that I was clicking. You know how can i do it?

Comment: @Janapiend sorry i did't get u , please elaborate your question.

Comment: For example when I click in image three the scroll put this image in the top.